# array looping strange behavior in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an indexed array which I've generated from an associative array with this code

```
$index_arr = array();
foreach($assoc_arr as $key => $val ){
   $index_arr .= $val;
}
```

when I print it with `print_r($index_arr);` it works fine. But when I try to print it with foreach I get an error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

```
foreach($index_arr as $one){
   echo "one: $one<br />";
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is the right syntax or am I too tired at this time of day?

Comment: +1 to counteract the downvote, since the question was clear and the downvote was not explained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You turn the array into a string by using .= operator on it. You want to use:

```
$index_arr[] = $val;
```

To append to the end.

Also in this particular case, you can just do:

```
$index_arr = array_values($assoc_arr);
```

This does exactly what your loop does.

Answer (score 2):

Needs to be this:

```
$index_arr = array();
foreach($assoc_arr as $key => $val ){
   $index_arr[] = $val;
}
```

Also

```
foreach($index_arr as $key=>$data){
   echo "Key: ".$key." Data: ".$data."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Or just use `$index_arr = array_values($assoc_arr);` :)

Comment: Thanks @Lukas just thought of that and was on my way back to edit, Cheers

Answer (score 2):

When you did `$index_arr .= $val;` PHP did a String operation. You need to do `$index_arr[]=$val;`

Answer (score 1):

```
$index_arr .= $val;
```

should be

```
$index_arr[] = $val;
```